# Macbook Pro constantly wants to shut down

Tags: macos, macbook, shutdown

With about 10 minute intervals I keep getting a popup-message saying "Are you sure you want to shut down?" With options; sleep, shutdown, cancel etc.

Usually I hit Cancel to remove the dialoge box, but if I leave it open the computer eventually short circuit and dies.

I've searched around for possible solutions, but all I can find is some problem with the 30" Cinema Display - which I do not have, or use.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Update:** The computer also has trouble booting - only way I can get it started is to boot while holding F1. If I do nothing but hit the power button the computer short circut right after the startup sound and Apple logo appears.

**Update 2:** It seems the popup only appears if the computer is idle. If I keep using the keyboard or trackpad nothing happens.

Comment: My suggestion would be to bring it to Apple and have it repaired.

Comment: @slhck Yes, I'll probably to that as soon as I'm back from vacation. Btw, do you know a way to disable the power button? I suspect the fault lies there...

Comment: Most probably not. Its function is mostly hardware based (or not accessible in OS X)